# Heroku (Python) Facebook app "Incorrect Padding" Error

Tags: python, facebook, heroku

I'm following the Heroku-Facebook App tutorial and get an error when trying to view my app in Facebook.
As opposed to the default app home page, the following error and traceback appears on screen.

```
TypeError
TypeError: Incorrect padding

Traceback (most recent call last)

File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1306, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1294, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))

File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1062, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1060, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()

File "/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1047, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

File "/app/exampleap
```

What are the specific steps that need to be taken to fix this error?

Comment: Your traceback got truncated.

Comment: The answer below worked for me - if it worked for you can you please accept the answer?  Helps you and the community!

Comment: please mark this ticket as reproducible https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/403883149689342

Answer (score 6):

in your app, change this line:

```
data = json.loads(urlsafe_b64decode(str(encoded_data[1])))
```

into this line:

```
data = json.loads(urlsafe_b64decode(str(encoded_data[1]) + (64-len(encoded_data[1])%64)*"="))
```

It works for me